# Excel VBA - Set Cell Value to Variable Adjacent to All Cells that Are Not Blank

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple reports that I need to compile into a single master file following specific steps, then put a date to the left of the new data. The steps that need to be followed are:

1. Open a file in Directory
2. Set a variable based on the file name to be used in a later step (I am using an InputBox function for this)
3. Copy all cells with data in column A from that file
4. Paste the cell data into the first blank cell in column B for my master file
5. **If there is data in column B and the adjacent cell in column A is blank, change that cell's value to the variable chosen in Step 2**
6. Close the file and open the next file in the directory

So basically, it needs to open File X, copy everything from column A of File X to column B of the Master, then insert a date in column B of the master for each row that has data in column B

I'm stuck on Step 5 and cannot figure out a way to find all cells that had data pasted into them from Step 4 and set the value of all cells directly to the left of them.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportGroups()
Dim fPATH As String, fNAME As String
Dim LR As Long, NR As Long
Dim wbGRP As Workbook, wsDEST As Worksheet
Dim dateChooser As Variant
Dim cell As Range


Set wsDEST = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")


Application.DisplayAlerts = False

fPATH = "C:\<path>\"       'remember the final \ in this string

fNAME = Dir(fPATH & "*")        'get the first filename in fpath

Do While Len(fNAME) > 0
    Set wbGRP = Workbooks.Open(fPATH & fNAME)   'open the file
    LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  'how many rows of info?

    If LR > 3 Then

        dateChooser = InputBox("Enter date based on this file name: " & fNAME)

        ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & LR).Copy
        wsDEST.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValue

        ' This is where I need to set the value of all cells adjacent to the pasted cells

    End If

    wbGRP.Close False   'close data workbook
        fNAME = Dir         'get the next filename
Loop
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: When you are working accross multiple work books, it is extremely important that you properly qualify your objects with a workbook/sheet. You have unqualified ranges and instances of `ActiveSheet` which should be srapped

Comment: Kudos for `Option Explicit`

Comment: I believe `Range("A" & LastRow + 1 & "A" & LastRow + LR)` is the range you're looking for (where LastRow is the last filled cell in Column `A` of `wsDEST`)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this.

1. You need to calculate your last row for each work book (destination and import) and you are currently doing so for just one book it looks like. For your destination book, the first available blank row (`LR`) will change every time you paste in a new range so this needs to be recalculated inside the loop before you open another book. On your import books, each file will presumably have varying rows, so this needs it's own last row calculation (`LR2`).
2. I qualified your sheets where `ws` which refers to `Sheet1` on your destination book. We will then use `wbGRP.Sheets(1)` which will reference the first sheet on each import book you open. This may be need to be corrected (*Pending response from you in comments*)
3. For **Step 5**, you will need to loop through your newly pasted data on `ws`. Where these rows exist can be deduced from your variables `LR` and `LR2`. Then just check if `Column A` is blank inside loop, and output `dateChooser` on desired column. I am pasting `dateChooser` in `Column B` here (*Also pending response from you in comments*)
4. Kudos on having `Option Explicit`. I did re-organize a few things here (Declare statics outside of screen updating, group like variables, etc.

This is not tested. Will be happy to make edits when you get to questions in comments

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportGroups()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim fPATH As String, fNAME As String
Dim LR As Long, LR2 As Long, i As Long
Dim wbGRP As Workbook, dateChooser As Variant

fPATH = "C:\<path>\"
fNAME = Dir(fPATH & "*")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Do While Len(fNAME) > 0
        Set wbGRP = Workbooks.Open(fPATH & fNAME)   'open the file
        LR = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row  'how many rows of info?

        If LR > 3 Then
            dateChooser = InputBox("Enter date based on this file name: " & fNAME)
            LR2 = wbGRP.Sheets(1).Range("A" & wbGRP.Sheets(1).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            wbGRP.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A" & LR2).Copy
            ws.Range("B" & LR).End(xlUp).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            For i = LR To (LR + LR2 - 1)
                If ws.Range("A" & i) = "" Then ws.Range("B" & i) = dateChooser
            Next i
        End If

        wbGRP.Close False
        fNAME = Dir
    Loop
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: congratz on 5k rep :)

Comment: Something in this revised script has caused the paste function to no longer work. I threw in a MsgBox after the line to copy the data to confirm that was still working correctly, so something with how the line for pasting the data caused it to no longer work.

I tried moving the "For" loop to my old script and adding in the appropriate variables, but that didn't work either. It still copied the data from the other files over but did not assign the dates.

Comment: Well, I asked about 3 clalrifying questions in the comments yesterday and you did not answer. You should not post your question until you are ready to tend to it because volunteers waste their time studying your problem and when it takes you a day to respond, we have to re-read your problem and catch back up. Given that this is volunteer time donated to you, that's not an ideal situation.  Won't have time to revisit this until Mon sorry

Comment: Sorry, I am new to using the site, but I'm not seeing any clarifying questions from you. I see "Kudos for Option Explicit", and to avoid using ActiveSheet when using multiple workbooks. Then I see one comment from someone else. I am unfortunately unable to remain 100% vigilant on comments on my question, as I can only access this site at specific times due to scheduling. I was relying on the email notifications to alert me when there was change, but I only got a single email after the three comments were left and you created this answer.

Comment: I deleted the questions when I posted this. I can revisit your question on monday